# MagicaVoxel .vox file format | Where is the position stored?

Tags: file-format, magicavoxel

**Back Story**: Here is the format I am following to read .vox files into my engine: [.vox file format](https://github.com/ephtracy/voxel-model/blob/master/MagicaVoxel-file-format-vox.txt)
I understand how to actually read the voxel data. However, I do not understand where the object coordinates are stored. For example, when importing many models from a .vox file all the objects aren't given a position so you need to manually place them where they need to go. This is annoying because if you have 100 objects in a scene that are placed correctly in MagicaVoxel then imported into my engine; each model needs to be moved to the correct position maually.

As of right now, I can find any documentation that shows each model's position is stored. I speculate that there is a way to store the position of models because when loading .vox files into MagicaVoxel all the objects remain in their original saved position.

**The Question**: How to extract object's moddel positions?

**Possible Confusion**: To my understanding, each voxel's coordinate is stored relitive to the object's space. I am trying to find the voxel object's world space not voxel space. Also, I know that you can store files in point cloud form to get world position but I need to use .vox file format to outline the chunks of objects.

Comment: Presumably the object position is stored in a chunk you're not processing yet? You could also try editing the position of an object in this "magicavoxel" editor and inspecting the changes in the corresponding vox file.

Comment: Thanks! I just compared the two file types and found something that is outside the chunk data that looks like object coordinates. I think that just solved the problem!

Comment: [link](https://github.com/ephtracy/voxel-model/blob/master/MagicaVoxel-file-format-vox-extension.txt) I found some extra documentation here.

Comment: Good find! I suggest you create a self-answer to your question with an extract of the relevant documentation

Answer (score 0):

Each voxel coordinates are stored in chunk data at the end of the file. However, there are multiple chunks that hold information other than position data. There are the three main chunk_id's each nTRN, nGRP, and nSHP. There are a few other chunks id's but they are not necessary for reading position data. The most important one is the nTRN chunk data which stores the position of each model along with its rotation. Rotation is stored in the _r chunk and translation in the _t chunk (note: this is all in the nTRN chunk). In the _t chunk, the data is formatted as follows: (number of bytes of the string stored in one integer) then (a string of 3 numbers giving position). Then that's it!